# Google Sheets formula for "if contains"

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to identify `IF` a list of items in one cell containing a value or string.

**EXAMPLE**

Cell `A1` contains `sites, sheets, docs, slides`.

I want cell `B1` to display a *1* *'if'* cell `A1` contains the string `sites`.

**FORMULA**

```
=if(A1 ?????? "sites", 1,0)
```

I'm unsure what to replace the `??????` within the above formula OR if this formula is possible. Any ideas on how to accomplish the desired outcome are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to colorize every row that contains a word, see here: https://janac.medium.com/how-to-format-a-row-in-google-sheets-if-it-contains-some-text-c51304e7040d

Answer (score 183, accepted):

You can use `REGEXMATCH`:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A1, "sites"), 1, 0)
```

To explain, `REGEXMATCH` returns true if and only if the argument is a substring of your string.

Comment: Using `regexmatch` would be simpler: `if(regexmatch(A1, "sites"), 1, 0)`.

Comment: The "if" isn't needed since regexmatch already returns a boolean, so just "REGEXMATCH(A1, "sites")"

Comment: The if is there so they can convert the true to a 1 or 0 if false

Comment: If parameters should be semicolon, not comma: `=IF(REGEXMATCH(A1, "sites"); 1; 0)`

Comment: The semicolon delimiter is dependent on your locale

Comment: How do I use this with `=COUNTIF`, where I supply a range and a condition, so I can't provide a single cell as an argument to `REGEXMATCH`.

Comment: This is case sensitive.

Comment: "REGEXMATCH returns true if and only if the argument is a substring of your string." this is a highly misleading statement. Strings are interpreted as regular expressions so there are **many** cases where this does not work.

Comment: `=REGEXMATCH(A1, "sites")*1` would be simpler if the goal is to output either 0 or 1

Comment: I prefer the formula made for this task, `N()`, so the whole thing would be: `=N(REGEXMATCH(A1, "sites"))`

Comment: Detailed explanation of this with screenshots here: https://janac.medium.com/how-to-format-a-row-in-google-sheets-if-it-contains-some-text-c51304e7040d

Comment: Semicolon is a global separator that works for all locales, so it's better for it being used here. Even if the user's locale requires a comma, a semicolon will still work. So semicolon should be used for all Google Spreadsheet codes.

Comment: @EmilStenström AuriellePerlmann is correct:  per documentation use commas in most locations and always in english: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en

Comment: @davidhartman00: I think this is locale dependent then. Didn't work for me with comma.

Answer (score 30):

If you, as Ryan Shillington suggests, want to know the number of cells within a range that has "sites" in it, you might try:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A100;"*sites*")
```

The * acts as a wildcard notion, so it will look for a match anywhere within the cell, not just an exact match for the whole cell.

I've also done this with  a cell reference instead of "*sites*", but then you have to add wildcard-asterixes to the text in the cell.

Comment: I haven't tested it but I expect you could add the asterisks in the formula when referencing a cell by doing `=COUNTIF(A1:A100; CONCATENATE("*", B1, "*"))`

Comment: I find this to be the simplest solution and can confirm that it works.

Answer (score 21):

This returns a `#VALUE!` error if the search term isn't found:

```
=IF(SEARCH("sites", B2) > 0, 1, 0)
```

---

This uses the same logic but catches the error and returns a `1`/`0` for success/failure:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("sites", B2) > 0, 0), 1, 0)
```

Comment: The first formula will never return 0 because `SEARCH(search_for, text_to_search, [starting_at])` will return an error when `search_for` do not be found.

Comment: How do I use `search` with `COUNTIF`?

Answer (score 11):

A solution without REGEX:

```
=if(iserror(FIND("sites",B2)),0,1)
```

capitalization matters and `if` logic must be reversed, given that answer is `true` when the string is not found.

Comment: This is basically the same as [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/95652/88163), but introducing the case sensitive thing. By the way the sample data provided by the OP includes `sheets` not `Sheets`.

Answer (score 5):

**This will return TRUE or FALSE:**

`=IFERROR(SEARCH("keyword",A1)>0, FALSE)`

Answer (score 4):

You're probably doing this because you want to know the count or average # of rows that have the word "sites" in it.  Assuming you have 100 rows of entries in column A, you can use this function to find out how many rows have the word "sites" in it:

```
=QUERY(A1:A100, "select count(A) where A like '%sites%'")
```

This is much faster than creating a column of 1s and zeros and then operating on that new column.

Comment: Can this work over a box instead of just a column?

Comment: Yup.  instead of `A1:A100` you could make it `A1:C100` and then write a query with columns A, B and C.

Answer (score 3):

If you go with the asterisks option and want a cell reference, you can use the CONCATENATE function to add the asterisks

`=COUNTIF(A1:A100,CONCATENATE("*",A1,"*"))`

Comment: `CONCATENATE` can be harder to read than using `&` to join the strings: `=COUNTIF(A1:A100, "*" &A1 &"*"))`

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(QUERY(A1, "where A contains 'sites'")<>"", 1, )
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

`Countif` is a memory hog and a lot of these answers depend on `not true` type approach (iferror etc.).  While that works, in a general better approach to conditions is seeking what is `true`.

Case not sensitive:

```
=isnumber(SEARCH("sites",A1))
```

Case sensitive:

```
=isnumber(SEARCH("sites",A1))
```

This will return `TRUE` if a match, or `FALSE` if not.