# Question about Google Sheet search function

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for a way to search a word in a range `B2:G10` so it would return `yes` if the word is in the range, or `no` if isn't.

Ex: the formula searches in the ranges `B1`, `B2` and `B3` each with a different word (ex: `hi`, `hello`, `goodbye`) and when the word `good` is searched, it gives me `no`, and if the word is `hello`, it gives me `yes`.

I've tried searching on this: [Google Sheets formula for "if contains"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95649/google-sheets-formula-for-if-contains), but when I try the formulas, they are not working.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I’ve seen some people try do do this, but a lot use substring or formulas that doesn’t work when I try it.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show what you tried.

Comment: I’ve edited it.

Comment: If you share a sample (editable) google sheet link, I can show you how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick way to do it with `if()` and `regexmatch()` [on a spreadsheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NWk-Amy5BfMixbItaqWGNNSmEymJg8jXgkBuzEgLHLI/edit?usp=sharing)

I used this formula

```
=if(
sum(ArrayFormula(
                 if(REGEXMATCH($B$2:$G$10,B14),1,0))
)>0,"yes","no")
```

`$B$2:$G$10` is the range where you search for a word in `B14`. 
It converts the range with false or true based on the match, then IF replace everything with 1 or 0. You could also use `switch()`.

Comment: I know I’m late, but is there a way to ignore the capital letters in your search function?

Comment: `regexmatch()` use a regex so it's capital sensitive. To solve this problem you can use `lower()` :`=if(
sum(ArrayFormula(
                 if(REGEXMATCH(lower($B$2:$G$10),lower(B14)),1,0))
)>0,"yes","no")`

Comment: I’ve just tried it, and the only problem is that if I write like: hel     and I have “hello” in the document, it will say yes, but it should say no.

Comment: @AZOM you can add operator `^` and `$` to indicate where to start and where to stop. Exemple for exactly `hel` you can type `^hel$` OR directly in the formula, juste replace `lower(B14)` with `lower("^"&B14&"$")`. This way, you'll always look for **exactly** what's in `B14`. I've updated the spreadsheet example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you’ve helped me a lot. :)