# Google Sheets for if contains "*"

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, regex

I have found the the regexmatch solution for substring: [Google Sheets formula for "if contains"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95649/google-sheets-formula-for-if-contains)

However, why for "*" is not working? I'm trying to make a condition if the name contains "*" it will exclude the stamp duty cost.

As for now, I'm using `=IF(REGEXMATCH(C11,"-"),0,ROUNDUP(G11/1000,0))`.
What is the explanation why "*" cannot be used?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the formula which didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a match condition if a name contains "*" (asterisk). However in the question that you cited, [Google Sheets formula for “if contains”](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/95660/196152), none of the `REGEXMATCH` answers use an asterisk.

In spreadsheets, the asterisk `(*)` is normally a wildcard character taking the place of any number of characters. But in regex, the asterisk has a special role as occurrence/Repetition Operator. To match an asterisk (or any other special character) in regex, you need to use a escape sequence prefix with a backslash like this: `\*`

Try this formula `=REGEXMATCH(A2,"\*")`.

It will return True if Cell A2 contains an asterisk, and False if it does not contain an asterisk.

---

**Example**

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

To determine if cell **A1** contains an `asterisk`, use:

```
=if(iserror(find(char(42),A1)),"No Asterisk","Asterisk")
```

[image]