# Counting substrings in a list of cells

Tags: google-sheets

I know how to check a single cell for a substring from [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95649/google-sheets-formula-for-if-contains), but I have a similar problem yet different:

I need the number of cells that contain a substring. For example, the texts are in column A:A and the substrings in C:C, with the counts planned to appear in D:D:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following in D1 will give you the count of occurrences in A1:A6 for each substring in C1:C7:

```
=map(C1:C7,lambda(substring,countif(A1:A6,"*"&substring&"*")))
```